# I have my AirPods out of sync and doing crackling sound

Tags: airpods

I have my AirPods out of sync and doing crackling sound, is it possible to fix?

I was trying to put them back to the case, closing, long pressing etc., but it didn't help

Comment: Have you rebooted whatever it is they're connected to? Does it do it on more than one device?